# Floating a div column under another div column

Tags: html, css

I have 4 containers within a main-container and trying to create a layout using it.

The first 3 containers are floated left and working as expected. The 4th container needs to be displayed under container-3 directly but its displayed only after the length of container-2.

How can I fix it?

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/prem1980/4D7ZS/10/

css

```
<div id ="main-container">
<div id = "container1">
    container 1
</div>
<div id = "container2">
    container 2
</div>
<div id = "container3">
    container-3
</div>
<div id = "container4">
    container-4
</div>

</div>
```

css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    /*background-color:#AFEEEE;*/
    background-color:white;
}
#main-container{
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}
#container1{
    height:80%;
    width:20%;
    background-color:grey;
    float:left;

}
#container2{
    height:90%;
    width:70%;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}

#container3{
    height:60%;
    width:10%;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;

}
#container4{
    height:20%;
    width:20%;
    background-color:yellow;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a 4th container in your fiddle..

Comment: I have added it now..

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: right` to your `#container4`. [**SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4D7ZS/20/)

```
#container4{
   height:20%;
   width:10%;
   background-color:yellow;
   float: right;
}
```

And remove `clear: both` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Put container-2, container-3, container-4 in a wrapper div. Then:

```
.wrapper-div {
float: left;
width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple wrap the div(3,4) inside the div

[LIVE WORKING LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4D7ZS/13/)

CSS
    html, body{
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        /*background-color:#AFEEEE;*/
        background-color:white;
    }
    #main-container{
        height:50%;
        width:100%;
    }
    #container1{
        height:80%;
        width:20%;
        background-color:grey;
        float:left;

```
}
#container2{
    height:90%;
    width:70%;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
a.34{
     width:10%;
    float:left;
}
#container3{
    height:60%;
    width:10%;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;

}
#container4{
    height:20%;
    width:10%;
    background-color:yellow;
 float:left;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id ="main-container">
<div id = "container1">
    container 1
</div>
<div id = "container2">
    container 2
</div>
<div class="a34">   
<div id = "container3">
    container-3
</div>
<div id = "container4">
    container-4
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

CSS

LIVE EXAMPLE :

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `Div 2` `Div 3` and `Div 4` inside of one `Div` and set the `Div`'s attributes to `float:left;` in `CSS`. Then they will all be next to `Div 1`

```
<div id ="main-container">
<div id = "container1">
container 1
</div>
<div id="float-left">
<div id = "container2">
container 2
</div>
<div id = "container3">
container-3
</div>
<div id = "container4">
container-4
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#float-left{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS fix for your `#container4`:

```
position:relative;
top:-30%; /* 30% is the height difference between #container2 and #container3 */
width:10%; /* Set it equel to the width of #container3 */
```